# Wiring three-axis accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer

I need to wire the following three-axis axis accelerometer:

http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/127c/0900766b8127c68c.pdf

Here when I click on ADXL335, the below link comes with some more information:
http://www.analog.com/en/mems-sensors/mems-inertial-sensors/adxl335/products/product.html

Here it says:
Single-supply operation 1.8 V to 3.6 V

I have 3 problems here:

1)  Is COM the common ground for Vs and X,Y,Z outputs?

2)  What is ST pin for? I couldn't figure out what it is used for?

3)  Should the power supply be constant? Can I use a battery? The reason I am asking these if I have 9V constant power supply and I use 3 resistors to make a voltage divider, would it be ok?

4)  How can I extend that 6-pin, 0.1 inch spaced header? Is there generic plug name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is COM the common ground for Vs and X,Y,Z outputs?

Yes, the evaluation board schematic shows the output filter capacitors from X, Y, and Z to COM.

> What is ST pin for? I couldn't figure out what it is used for?

Self test, check the datasheet, you probably don't need it.

> Should the power supply be constant? Can I use a battery? The reason I
>   am asking these if I have 9V constant power supply and I use 3
>   resistors to make a voltage divider, would it be ok?

No, use a proper regulator. See [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider).

> How can I extend that 6-pin, 0.1 inch spaced header? Is there generic
>   plug name?

That is about as generic a termination as you can get. Find yourself something through hole with .1" pitch on your favorite distributor's website. Look at Molex and Amphenol for a locking header and connector.

Comment: thanks one thing about the voltage regulation. should i buy a voltage regulator such as:http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/7812_voltage_regulator.jpg or if i would have an adjustable ac/dc adapter would it work?

Comment: Take a look at the LM317. That's a good part to have in your box.