# Voltage regulator from 24v to 3.7v

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I need to build a simple voltage regulator that can drop voltage from 24V(from a DC power supply) to 3.7V and supply at least 2A or more(up to 5A if possibile).

Can I just use a 2 resistor voltage devider? Or should I use a voltage regulator?

Comment: DC to DC converter would be more efficient

Comment: 2 resistor voltage divider is always a bad idea

Comment: Dropping 20 volts with 5 amps current => that's 100 watt power loss! You'll get a mighty hot voltage regulator! Please use a DC to DC converter.

Comment: Part of your question is answered in [When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider)

Answer (score 2):

For the reasons outlined by WhatRoughBeast, resistors are a very bad idea for voltage regulation.

For "realistic" DC-DC voltage regulation options, there are two, and only one is really feasible for your application:

1. Linear voltage regulator
2. DC-DC switching regulator

The first option, a linear regulator, is typically an integrated semiconductor device in a transistor-style package. In simple terms these devices drop excess voltage above the regulation voltage as heat across a semiconductor junction. Linear regulators are very easy to use - you connect the supply pin, the output pin, and a common ground, and you're off to the races. They also provide low ripple.

The problem with linear regulators is that you're dropping a voltage across a junction that a current is passing through - ie: all that power is wasted as heat. If you don't draw much power to begin with and your supply voltage is not much higher than your regulation voltage (for example: 5V to 3.3V), this isn't a big deal.

In your application this will be a problem though. Your power loss is equal to your current times the difference between the supply and output voltages:

\$P_{loss}= I_{load}\left ( V_{in} - V_{out} \right )=2A \left (24V-3.7V \right)=38.6W\$

That's almost 40W of heat you're dissipating in the regulator. That's some serious cooling required!

Instead, you'll need to use a DC-DC switching regulator. These devices use an inductor as a temporary energy storage device which is switched out very quickly. They do generate more noise and are more fiddly to set up than a linear regulator, but are typically 90% efficient at power conversion. They also have the advantage of being able to increase voltage (boost converter) as well as decrease it (buck converter). Some types (buck-boost) will do both in the same device, and other types can provide a negative voltage rail.

I find [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyHUfZxmP8s) from TI is really good at explaining the fundamentals of how and why they work. To actually *implement* one, you have a couple options.

Many companies sell easy-to-use finished modules, sometimes referred to as "linear regulator replacements." The advantage to these is that they're just as easy to use as a linear regulator, and some even come in industrial-friendly enclosures with screw terminals if you're adverse to making a PCB. The downside to these is that they're usually pretty expensive, especially for higher current output.

The other option is to buy a switching regulator chip and add all the external components (at minimum a diode, inductor, two filter capacitors, a resistor divider for feedback, and sometimes a MOSFET). This usually isn't too hard, but the design is a bit more interactive. Most manufacturers provide pretty good datasheets which outline the design process, part recommendations, and preferred PCB layout. If you deviate from these, make sure to simulate the design. Other than more work for design, the other disadvantage is that you will need to do a PCB (switching noise makes switched devices infeasible for breadboard construction).

Good luck with your project!

Comment: (Devil's advocate mode) How about *two* linear regulators to spread the heat dissipation between them? Handy if the OP wanted, say, a 12V DC supply too.

Comment: * two linear regulators *in series*.

Comment: You're still burning 40 watts of power either way... the only difference is that 20 watts is on each regulator, which is still a huge amount of power and is going to require a pretty decent heatsink. Why not just do the sensible thing and use a switcher?

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you can. And no, I see no way it's a good idea.

Let's take the easiest case - a 1-resistor divider (you use the load as the other). The drop across the resistor is 24 - 3.7 volts, let's call it 20. The load current is 5 amps, which means the resistor value is 4 ohms. So the power dissipated in the resistor is 20 x 5, or 100 watts. The power in the load is 5 x 3.7, or about 18 watts. That's no what I'd call efficient.

But wait - what happens if the load current changes? Well, then the voltage across the resistor changes, and the load voltage changes. Let's say the load drops to 2 amps. Now the voltage across the resistor is (V = I x R, remember?) 8 volts, and the load voltage is about 16 volts. Not real good regulation, I think you'll agree.

So how do you get around this? By adding a second resistor. Now the load current can change, and the load voltage won't change. As much. Depending on the resistors.

The useful phrase here is the Thevenin equivalent resistance, which is nothing more than the parallel value of the two resistors. And how to calculate this? Let's say that you want your 3.7 volts to change no more than 0.1 volts for a current range of 0 to 5 amps. Then the Thevenin equivalent resistance needs to be 0.02 ohm maximum. The two divider resistors have an approximate ratio of 5:1, which will give 4 volts rather than 3.7, but it's close enough for a quick understanding.

So we can say two things: R1 x R2 / (R1 + R2) = .02, and R2 / (R1 + R2) = 1/5. From this it follows that R1 = 0.1 ohms, and R2 = 0.0167 ohms. You see where this is leading.

So the total divider resistance is 0.1167 ohms. Total divider current with no load is about 206 amps, and the current through R1 (the top resistor) gets to 211 amps when the load is 5 amps. And power? Well, for the no-load condition, that's nearly 5000 watts.

So yes, you can use two resistors to divide down 24 volts to 3.7. And no, it's almost certainly not a good idea. Of course, if you're running an industrial process that needs a fairly constant 5 kW at 24 volts, you can work with that and it's a great idea.