# Take 7.5V from 12V battery

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I have two servos which take from 7V to 8V and I want to deliver this voltage from 12V batteries 4200 mAh.
I have tried using voltage divider but the result was so bad, I had 2V after applying the servo (load ).
What is the simplest way to deliver this amount of voltage without consuming a lot of current?
(I need a lot of solutions because sometimes I don't find the hardwares in my country.)

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149918/voltage-regulator-from-24v-to-3-7v?rq=1

Comment: Switching Regulator. Linear Regulator. Which depends on how much current your servos draw. There are many simple switcher ICs which require few external components, e.g. the MC34063. But I can't say if that is useable without more information about your servos.

Comment: The current consumption of your servos are important when you want to choose a DC-DC converter or an LDO.

Comment: be aware that a servo which uses 300mA when in normal operation may draw 2+Amps when stalled, and having a 2A power supply for each servo will get extremely expensive. You need to do some sacrificing/protection circuitry to avoid these issues.

Comment: Depending on the battery type, you may be able to open it and reconfigure its cells. Reduce the number of cells in series to lower the voltage to 7-8 volts.  This avoids the loss and weight of a regulator or resister set.  Can be very dangerous to do, depending on the battery type and how much heat you apply soldering, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can benefit from an off-the-shelf DC/DC step-down converter module. They are compact, they have good efficiency and they are hassle-free, i.e. you don't have to design all the circuitry needed to build one from the ground up using an IC and reading its datasheet to get all the parameters right. There are some models which are really cheap, too!

Off the top of my head, see [this Pololu page](https://www.pololu.com/category/131/step-down-voltage-regulators).

As @BattleHamster said, you need to select one knowing what's the maximum current your servos will be drawing (with some headroom for safety).