# Voltage Divider?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, voltage-divider

I am designing a piezo micropump driver that feeds into a piezo electric transducer that mists a liquid.

Both of these designs have been testedindependently and now its time to integrate.

BST of DRV2700 is a 100V regulated output. I already have another switching supply in my design and really want to avoid a 3rd one. Because the BST output is regulated, could it be okay to simply use a voltage divider get the 100V down to the necessary 30V?

I know a switching buck converter would do the trick but is there any reason I wouldn't just use a voltage divider here? If my 'supply' of 100 V is regulated then theoretically my 30V would also be regulated, correct?
[image]

Comment: Please explain "BST". We can't answer your question without knowing what the 30 V load is and that isn't clear from your question. Please proof read it from the point of view of someone who has no idea what the subject matter is.

Comment: For switch-mode IC's the highest input voltage I know of is 60vdc. Assuming your BST pins can source the current, you will need a transistor-based Vreg to step the voltage down to 50vdc. But you have not stated what your source or load current is.

Comment: BST is the output of the internal boost converter. It outputs 100V and 750mA. The load @ pump1 is about 400mA peak and the load at piezo1 is 50mA. Piezo1 is a single piezo electric transducer used for mist generation while pump1 is a single piezo in an enclousure that allows it to pump a liquid.  I am really trying to ask the simple question -- If you have a regulated output, does it make sense to use a voltage divider rather than a switching buck converter to knock my 100V down to 30?

Comment: How much current does this 30 volt supply need?

Comment: Piezo1 needs 50mA

Comment: A voltage divider is not a power supply. As soon as you draw any current from it, the voltage will change.

Comment: Related: [When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/)

Comment: Okay, a voltage divider is not what I am looking for. I guess I need a way to step down 100V to 30V.

Comment: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND8098-D.PDF may help. There definitely are buck converters that can work with 100V inputs, but they are somewhat more difficult to find.

Comment: Power in dropper R = Pr = Vdro x Ipiezo = (100-30) x 50 mA = 3.5W. A 10W resistor to a 10W 30V zener would "work" [tm] . If piezo load removed Pzener ~= 30V x 50 mA = 1.5W. Higher in practice as R will be sligghtly smaller than limit to allow some headroom. Very wasteful on power but doable.