# wrong voltage when splitting from 5V to 3.3V

Tags: voltage, pullup, mems

I am trying to connect the MMA5452Q accelerometer to arduino on 5V (later it will be substituted with attiny85, hence the 5V voltage).
It works just fine when i supply arduino's 3.3V. When i try the 5V supply and split it with resistors (R1, R2, R3) the accelerometer does not work any more.
I measured the voltage of the circuit. It is 1.1V but MMA5452Q requires 1.6-3.3V. I was trying different combinations but i am afraid that doing it blindly at some point I will just burn the chip.
What is going on here? Could anyone tell me how to connect it so the voltage maches? (And how to calculate this - so I dont need to ask every time :)  )

P.S.
R5 and R4 are pull ups required by accelerometer's documentation. Works when the circuit is powered with 3.3V

P.S.S.
I am not an electrical engineer. I am hoping that this question is not terribly stupid.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwZFp6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: See [When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/106718/29811)

Comment: Yep. You're using a *loaded* voltage divider. This doesn't work.

Comment: ahh i see... so there is no way around and i need to buy the voltage regulator...?

Comment: @Chris would definitely the easiest way to go. These things do what you need and [cost cents](http://de.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?catalogId=15001&langId=-3&storeId=10161&categoryId=700000004335&sort=P_PRICE&showResults=true&pf=311439590,311439591,311439594,311439600,313248015).

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regulator. Buffer with an opamp. Have OUT connected to IN- and your +3.3 from the divider connected to IN+. Remove other connections to the divider. Run the opamp from the +5V rail. Use the opamp OUT to run the +3.3V rail with the pull resistors etc. Make sure the opamp can supply the current required by the accelerometer.

Comment: Surely this is larger and more complicated than just buying a regulator?

Comment: Don't mean to be mean, but: an Opamp with a voltage divider **is** a voltage regulator, and nothing else. Just a relatively complicated, uncompensated, untested and potentially expensive one.

Comment: @pjc hehe, collision

Comment: It's a fair option and, if you have a spare op-amp from a multipack already on-board, a better one than an extra regulator. It can't be called a bad answer.

Comment: I think in terms of getting things working for OP my solution was the better option. It's not like he's designing for HVM. Sure, wait till you can buy a voltage regulator, you guys must just have more free time than me.