# Why use a ten-percent rule-of-thumb for a bleeder current on a voltage divider?

Tags: voltage-divider

A book I am reading recommends "The 10 Percent Rule" as a method for selecting resistors for a voltage divider:

[image]

The book claims it is a standard method. My question is: why choose a bleeder current that is ten percent the load current? Why not less? It seems to me that a smaller bleeder current would be more efficient: less bleeder current would result in less power consumption by the bleeder resistor (P=IV, I decrease) and the first resistor (the current in the first resistor is the sum of the currents through the bleeder and the load. The bleeder current decreases while the load current stays the same, so overall current also decreases)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It is an arbitrary value selected by the design engineer. 10% is actually an upper limit, as power is wasted as heat. 5% would be ok with me, but the term 'bleeder resister' is an umbrella for many things. To drain a power supply when OFF to avoid a shock hazard. To act as a minimum load for SMPS power supplies (from 20 years ago) that had two output transformers for a variety of voltages, so the main supply needed a minimum load.

Comment: If the bleeder sets the maximum voltage rise if the load shuts off, that may be desireable to prevent overvoltage to some unknown load.  ( it may be better than no R2 in some cases)

Comment: Is it only me or this design seems AWFUL to anyone else? What happens to the voltage on the load if the load current changes by 50%. For a voltage divider to work independently of load changes, its current shall be ten times BIGGER than load current, not ten times smaller

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami  perhaps the circuits get better the further one gets into the book - this circuit may only be presenting the simple concepts and are not complete production or useable designs...

Comment: This is an ancient rule that was applied to vacuum-tube designs, where the high no-load voltage wasn't an issue. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/worksheets/voltage-divider-circuits/

Comment: @SolarMike is correct, this is towards the beginning of an entry-level book

Answer (score 6):

This is actually an incorrect interpretation of the "10% rule", as I understand it. Or, perhaps, there are two of these rules used in different situations!

If you are simply scaling a voltage, you actually want your *load* current to be around 10% of your *divider's* current.

This is because you don't want the divider's output voltage to vary much when the load changes. And the load *will* change! Either because it is doing something intelligent (with a microcontroller, for example) or simply because ambient conditions (like temperature) will change.

Yes, this wastes a lot of power. This is the reason to use a regulator to power a load instead of a divider. If you like, please see this [related answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/106725/38335) to a different question.