# How many watt-hours in two AA cells?

Tags: power, batteries

If I wire 2 AA cells with a nominal capacity of 2 Ah and a nominal voltage of 1.5V each in series, then I'll get 3V with 2 Ah, right?  Is that, thus 6 Wh?

If I wire them in parallel, I get 1.5V with 4 Ah?  Is that also 6 Wh?

Comment: More like 5 Wh. You don't use 1.5V when calculating Wh because the battery voltage declines during discharge. The average voltage is more like 1.3V or 1.25V.

Comment: What AA cells? NiMH, alkaline, zinc chloride...? And what is the current draw? Continuous use or intermittent?

Comment: @Indraneel Which of those AA's you mention are 1.5V?  Which would have a capacity of 2000 mAh?

Comment: @Indraneel, they're alkaline and we're pulling 150 mA intermittently.  There's a 400 mA spike during startup, then about 25 seconds at 150 mA.  Most of the time, the components are in deep sleep and draw substantially less current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initial answer: Yes
Possibly: No: see update
Formula: 
     Power Capacity [Wh] = #Batteries * Voltage * Electric Charge [Ah]
Divided in Series/Parallel:

> ```
> Connection   Voltage            Electric Charge [Ah]  Power Capacity [Wh]
> ----------   -----------------  --------------------  -------------------
> Series       2 * 1.5 V = 3   V  1 * 2 Ah = 2 Ah       3   V * 2 Ah = 6 Wh
> Parallel     1 * 1.5 V = 1.5 V  2 * 2 Ah = 4 Ah       1.5 V * 4 Ah = 6 Wh
> ```

- This means by using batteries in series, the voltage is increased (sometimes needed by the circuit).
- Using batteries parallel extends the 'running time' of the circuit without the batteries to be replaced/charged.
- Of course combinations are possible (e.g. using a set of batteries with 2 parallel sets of 3 batteries in series, resulting in 4.5 V, 4 Ah).

**Update**

It seems it is load dependent. My knowledge about batteries is not so high, and it seems Misunderstood's answer shows more insight.

However, I rather will keep my answer for all useful comments below.

Comment: Pfew.  Finally some of this is making sense.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: You're welcome. It would be strange if it would be different.

Comment: Fair, but I had made some assumptions in a previous question that were incorrect.  Oddly enough, I think that my conclusion was still correct, but only because in the case of my other question, the proportions are more important than the units.

Basically, I was looking at mAh and I was summing them.  Someone told me I should work with watt-hours.  Once I did, the proportions were the same as they were when I erroneously added the mAh together in series.

Thanks again!!

Comment: Welcome again :-) Btw, I'm also a beginner. Normally batteries are put in series to achieve the voltage required for a circuit. And if you need the circuit to run longer without new batteries, than putting batteries in parallel is the solution. Of course both can be combined (so using batteries in parallel and series within one circuit). Like using 6 batteries to get 4.5V and 4Ah.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to figure out how to understand my options with LDO regulators and switching regulators.  I'm trying to drive a 3.3V circuit with 4 AA batteries, but it looks like 45% of the power consumed is just heating up the pass element.  So, I could use 3 AA batteries and get better efficiency.  Or, I could stick with 4 and a switching regulator.  But, should I step down from 6 to 3.3 or step up from 3 to 3.3 (with a 2s2p configuration)?  Worse, I have no idea how to start figuring that out. :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know that much about LDOs.. When using 3 batteries of 1.5V in series, you might run in problems when the batteries are getting empty, because there is just 0.2V headroom.

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not quite this simple. This is a pretty good estimate, but battery voltage isn't constant, so it's not exact. Not to mention that battery capacity can vary based on discharge rate.

Comment: @D.Patrick: you figure out the step up/step down conundrum by looking at how efficient regulators are.  Synchronous buck converters are generally best, but modern boost converters aren't far behind.  Note, however, that most dry cells (and, incidentally, NiMH cells) are good down to 0.9V/cell -- leave much more than that on the table and you're throwing away energy.  So if you're going to step down to 3.3V, start with four cells (0.9V * 4 = 3.6V, which is enough headroom for a synchronous buck).

Comment: @D.Patrick, there is information in [this unrelated answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/106725/38335) which may be helpful regarding the regulators. You can skip the first third of the answer :)

Comment: Hey, thanks everybody!!  It seems obvious now that using an LDO to step down to 3.3V from 6V is probably a pretty bad idea.  I'm leaning toward sticking with 4 AA batteries in series and using a buck converter to get down to 3.3V.

Comment: An alkaline AA's capacity is rated from 1.5V down to 0.8V.  So is 3V or 1.5V the voltage that should be used to calculate Wh?   The same that you cannot say  you can get  1.5V @ 100 mA for 20 hours from a 2,000 mAh alkaline.  So I do not believe the OP can get 6Wh.

Comment: i actually have the same question, but i actually doubt a bit the method of just doing

Power Capacity [Wh] = #Batteries * Voltage * Electric Charge [Ah]

It would be useful if the device uses constant current, however if it's constant power such as a circuit fed by a buck converter because the voltage is actually changing significantly over state of charge, so you actually have to integrate over voltage, that particular number seems to be somewhat hard to find.

Comment: @Misunderstood ... I think you are right, my knowledge about batteries is not as big as yours. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @diegogmx I think Misunderstood's answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 8):

> 2 AA cells with a nominal capacity of 2 Ah and a nominal voltage of 1.5V  each in series, I'll get 3V with 2 Ah, right? Is that, thus 6 Wh?

The 1.5V of an AA is not like the nominal 1.2V of a NiMH. The estimation of Wh by V x capacity works much better for NiMH and Li-ion where the nominal voltage is mid point in the discharge curve. NiMH fresh charge voltage is 1.6V and Li-ion 4.2V, and cutoffs 1V and 3V.  AA fresh voltage is 1.5V and cutoff is 0.8V, very unlike NiMH and Li-ion.

So no, 8 Wh would not be correct for an alkaline AA. It would be 6 Wh if the battery voltage was a constant 3V over the lifespan of the battery.  Notice, in the *MilliAmp-Hours Capacity* bar chart below, it says "Continuous discharge to 0.8V".  The 2 Ah is not at a constant 3V.  An AA has a 2 Ah capacity only with a specific load.

Both the capacity and voltage are dependent on the load and therefore the Wh is also load dependent.

More information is needed. Need to know the instantaneous current and voltage over the lifetime of the battery.  Even at that it is not easy to calculate the watt hours used.

An empirical approach would be easier.  Continuously record the current and voltage of the battery while your device is operating.  Then calculate the Wh for small periods of time and sum the results.

---

The capacity of an AA varies with load's current draw and whether or not it is a continuous load.

[image]
Source: [Energizer E91 AA Datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/e91.pdf)

---

The voltage and discharge curve is also load dependent.

[image]
Source: [Energizer E91 AA Datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/e91.pdf)

---

If the load is not continuous the discharge curve is much different than a continuous curve.

[image]
Source [bossmanbattery.com](http://bossmanbattery.com/klient-page/128-specif-lr6-profi-alkaline.html)