# What is the best way to convert a 10V power supply into a 5V power supply?

Tags: power, resistors, electrical, electricity

If you were given a 10V power supply and wanted to power USB devices with it, how would you convert it to 5V? Would using a voltage divider splitting it into 2 5V lines be the best? What ohm resistors would you use? I believe using any two resistors of the same value would split it into 5V. Why exactly would the resistance values matter?

Comment: a voltage divider would be nearly the worst

Comment: Define "best". Simplest? Highest efficiency? Least EMI? Least heat? Cheapest BOM? What's your expected current consumption?

Comment: might want to search ebay for "DC buck XL4015" for the "best", or if you want to be cheap, "DC buck LM2596", then wire that to a USB female socket. Or, if you don't need a ton of power for the USB devices, "DC buck 12v 5v usb" hits a lot of ready-made fixed 5v output modules (you can feed a "12v" buck 10v just fine). Also, you can simply get a "usb car charger" from the dollar store and crack it open or use a cigarette lighter socket (like one cut-off of a socket splitter) to wire it to the 10v to get a cheap but low-power and electrically noisy solution.

Comment: "Mini360" if you want cheap. but it's only a little cheaper than LM2596 smaller and better peak capacity though.

Comment: There is no best way unless you specify the NFRs (non functional requirements) of the solution. EG time to do it, cost, size, power loss, heat , reliability, yada yada. The function requirement is 10v to 5v but there are many ways to do that.
And selecting between the ways to find the 'best' requires you specify the constraints and NFRs on the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider)

Answer (score 23):

If you want to convert the voltage to 5 volts, you should not use a resistance-voltage divider. That way you will indeed create 5 volts, but as soon as you apply a load the voltage will drop.
Instead, you have two options in general to regulate voltage. The first option using a linear regulator, and the second option is using a switch-mode power supply.

### Linear Regulator

A linear regulator like for example the LM317 is a simple device that will act like a constantly adjusting resistor to lose the superfluous voltage (in your case 5v). The main advantage of using a linear regulator is that provides a nice and clean voltage source, without ripple. This is useful if the device your are powering requires no noise. Another advantage is that linear regulators usually are cheap, and easy to get.
The main disadvantage of a linear regulator is that it dissipates the superfluous voltage as heat. This way it is not efficient at all. In your example that translates to roughly 50% efficiency, since you only use 50% of the voltage.

### Switch-mode power supply

A switch-mode power supply uses somewhat more advanced circuitry to only draw as much current as it needs in the input to then convert that energy to the required voltage. In your case, you would want to use a buck-converter, where it will take 10V at a 50% duty cycle to create 5V.
The main advantage of a SMPS is that it is rather efficient, and thus will not generate a lot of heat. The disadvantage is that they generate the required voltage based on a switching principle with frequencies varying from a couple kilohertz to a few megahertz, which introduces some ripple on your output voltage. This ripple is often expressed as a percentage of the output voltage.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter

Comment: And once you get up to an amp or so the heat problems of a linear regulator become a PITA to deal with, making switchers look a lot more attractive.

Comment: Another option in some cases may be to use a combination of a charge-pump voltage converter and a linear regulator.  Although such voltage converters would mainly be used in cases where the step-down ratio is far enough above 2:1 to make up for conversion and regulation losses, I have seen some 3:2 ones advertised.  Switching power supplies require coils, which tend to have a certain minimum size.  Charge-pump converters use capacitors, which may be smaller and cheaper, but are generally limited to operating at fixed voltage ratios, making it necessary to follow them with other regulators.

Answer (score 3):

Since you’re powering USB, that’s up to 2.4A for battery charging or 1A for typical USB power. That’s a fairly high current. From 10V source, a linear regulator or resistor-divider network approach will shed tremendous amounts of power.

The practical and cost-effective solution is to use DC-DC conversion. Fortunately, with the popularity of USB this is widely available and inexpensive - for example, as a USB car adapter (12V-5V) which should run just fine on 10V.

Comment: Quasi-compliant USB devices won't draw more than 500 milliamps when merely connected to power and given no information about the source (*actually* compliant ones no more than 100 mA); of course there are things which are not remotely compliant.  But most phones won't charge at more than the baseline 500 mA rate without indication of the supply capability - a decent car charger may solve the problem of getting the phone to use a higher rate for the asker.

Comment: That’s a whole ‘nother issue (DP/DN termination ID) which is solveable by buying an appropriate charger. Even that is confusing since there’s the USB way, the Apple way, the Sony way, etc.

Comment: Exactly, a charger *might* dodge dealing with that (though it also might assume in a vehicle electrical system a more capable supply than the unspecified power output of the one the asker has)

Answer (score 1):

*Would using a voltage divider splitting it into 2 5V lines be the best?*

No, use a voltage regulator and consider that using a switched mode regulator is likely to be the most power efficient if your load current is more than a few milliamps.

Answer (score 0):

"best" is when you can reconfigure the load to want 10V or reconfigure the supply to provide 5V. If you can't do that you'll have to compromise.

If efficiency is most important use a buck converter

If Price is most important use a divider or a dropper

Between those two extremes use a linear regulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't split it into two separate 5V lines--there are USB2 devices that need more than 500mA of power and get it by connecting to two ports.  Such a device would be shorting +5V to +0V.  These days it's unlikely anyone would build such a device (they would make it USB3 instead even if the transfer speed didn't matter) but they exist in the wild.