# Potentiometer getting burned out while connected between motor and 5V 2A ac adaptor

Tags: potentiometer

I have an old trimmer with damaged battery. I know it is more economical and reliable to buy a new one rather than repairing it, but I find it interesting to play with electronics/electricals. I want to run it from a 5V 2A mobile charger (it was running on a 1.2V rechargeable cell earlier).

I tried my own voltage divider using resistors but the trimmer motor didn't move and resistors work like heating coils. When I directly connected the motor to the power supply (5V 2A) the motor worked rigorously. I know it will burn if I use it longer. Then I tried a potentiometer (22 kΩ) to find it works at first but also end up with fire and smoke. What did i do wrong (or did I do anything right)?

Comment: *did i do anything right* - not so far. Try buying a buck converter (5 volts input to 1.2 volts output).

Comment: control that voltage and current.  1.2V is tiny compared to 5V.  5V drives over 4X the current through the same load.  If you need to make a 1.2V source from a 5V source, opt for a capacitor and voltage regulator.

Comment: I think this may work for you..
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00QVONO20/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 or search via Amazon for this..
HiLetgo 12V~40V 10A PWM DC Motor Speed Control Switch Controller Voltage Regulator Dimmer for Arduino

Comment: A 22 kW resistor would be the size of a fridge or minibus. Do you mean 22 kΩ?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but very relevant: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider

Comment: you can buy 100W potentiometers on ebay for under $10, I use them for testing linear power supplies, but adjustable output bucks are even cheaper and are WAY more efficient.

Comment: @ChrisLewis unfortunately, its input support starts from 12V. Hope there will be a variant starting from 5V

Comment: @Transistor Yes. it was 22 kOhm. I just mistyped it as kW

Comment: what about putting a resistor in series? does it work that way?