# AC signal gets unwanted DC offset when connected to circuit

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, ac, mains, signal-processing

Hi im a 4th year ELE student and I am creating a circuit which outputs 120khz square wave burst when it detects zero crossings from the input ac signal.

Here is the circuit diagram[image]

Op amp 1 converts the ac signal coming from the transform to a square wave. The coupling capacitor changes the wave from +/- 5v into 10v to 0v. The lm7805 limits the voltage to 5v so it is a 5v to 0v square wave output. The atmega328p interprets the square wave rise and fall as the zero crossings of the original input sinewave. The second op-amp generates a 120khz square wave. The atmega328p toggles the transistor on/off to output this 120khz square wave when there are zero crossings. The circuit works as intended when using a power supply to input the 20v p-p sinewave.

The issue arises when I use a transformer to convert the VAC from the wall receptacle to input the sinewave instead. I am using a 1.1VA transformer it outputs approximately 13.2v p-p after the capacitor divider. The input wave looks like this after it goes through the capacitors (ignore channel 1):
[image]

Once it is plugged into op amp 1 a DC offset voltage appears which causes the square wave generated to not have a duty cycle of 50%:
[image]

here is what it looks like when I use a signal generator instead of the transformer:
[image]

here is what it looks like when i use an LM741 instead of a TL081 for op amp 1:

[image]

Lastly when i use an 9v 450mA ac-ac power supply instead of the transformer the issue is not present. Is it because the transformer is rated 1.1VA? is this not enough? What else could be the issue?

Comment: Are you getting a proper ground?

Comment: At least two problems: The glaring one is that 10k GND reference...it should have a much lower equivalent resistance than 5k. When you measure DC volts from **V+** to **GND**, is it the same magnitude as **V-** to **GND**? Other problem: OA1 inverting input requires a DC path to GND since there are currents here (however tiny).

Comment: Hey i put a 10k resistor from OA1 inverting input to ground and it solved the problem. Also for your question about the DC volts of V+ to GND. Initially i used 2 10k resistors to split the voltage equally. However when i put the additional op-amp and the atmega328p into the circuit, the voltage ratio was skewed. This is why i swapped for a trim pot so that i can adjust the resistance to output exactly 5v from V+ to gnd and -5v from V- to gnd. I dont fully understand the first problem you mentioned

Comment: I've got to ask what inspired you to (ab)use a 7805 in that way? It's a voltage regulator for building *power supplies*, not a level shifter!

Comment: And a 10k pot is of no use as a virtual ground. You need something significantly 'stiffer' than that.

Comment: Why not use the Atmega128 to generate the 120kHz directly instead of using it to drive that transistor which alternately short-circuits the output of the opamp oscillator?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider