# Power supply to an A4988 driver

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, stepper-motor, motor-controller, stepper-driver

I am starting to use the driver A4988, typically used for NEMA 17 motors and many others. As you may know, it has to separated VCC/GND pair of pins, one to supply the driver, the other for the motor and they usually work at different voltages. I was wondering if it's possible to first, set up a voltage divider, so that there are 5V across the first resistance and 12V across the other. Then I would connect the terminals of the first resistance to the pair of terminals supplying for the driver and the terminals of the second resistance to the ones for the motor. My question is if this is possible as I am connecting the same terminal for GND in one case and VCC for the other. For me, it makes sense, but I smell there may be something wrong. If someone could please clarify this, and why it would or wouldn't work would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to Page 18 of [the A4988 datasheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/a4988-datasheet.pdf),

> The GND pins must be tied together externally by connecting to the PAD
> ground plane under the device.

Why? Page 13 shows that there are effectively diodes between the power PAD and each of the GND pins.
So I suspect that, if the GND pins are connected to significantly different voltage, forcing current through those diodes,
the chip would quickly overheat and burn out some, possibly all of its functions.

It's better to connected the logic power supply VDD to some sort of voltage regulator, rather than a 2-resistor voltage divider -- see
[When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider)