# Generate multiple voltages

Tags: pcb-design

I have a 24V supply and want to switch 24V, 12V and 5V simultaneously with one switch. The voltages serve as Digital Inputs at 3 different Interfaces. Because the power consumption is of minor importance in my experimental setup I thought of simply generating the voltages with a simple resistor network. Is this a feasible way?

Comment: What sort of interfaces, and at what speed will they switch?

Comment: You might not be worried about power consumption, but the input impedance of the circuit can affect resistor networks. Also, what are you using to switch the voltage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider)

Comment: The switch is switching every once on a while. Its simply a manual switch. It is actually a problem that I don't know for sure which Inputs I am dealing with. The 5V is a high impedance DI. Its not that I want to build multiple voltage rails for supply purpose (like discussed in the linked discussion) there I would of course use a Line regulator

Comment: Would a Voltage Buffer resolve the problem? If yes, which one to use for the given voltages?