# How to use resistors to lower voltage?

Tags: voltage, resistors

I want to use a resistor to lower 3V to 1.8V but I'm not sure which one to use.  How do I decide which one I should use?

Comment: A resistor to lower voltage is almost always the wrong solution.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: It depends what you are doing, i.e. what do you need the 1.8V for and how much current, what load you have, etc, and resistors can even be a completely wrong solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider)

Comment: a resistor resists the current instead of the voltage. when you add a resistor such as a restive wire between 3V and 0Vground, then eventually around halfway the wire the voltage will be halved, this is also the case when connecting a normal wire, a restive wire however will limit the current and so will not as easily set your circuit on fire.

they are mostly only used for reading voltages, or refference voltages, due to the lack of current.

Comment: however if you have a led for example which has a voltage drop of 1.8v then you will only want to add one resistor in front of it, in a ideal world that resistor will always drop the voltage to 1.8V no matter the value, however in reality this differs, but the function of the resistor there is not to regulate the voltage, but instead to regulate the current just like in the voltage divider, a wire would work just as well it would just have a much higher current.

Comment: so if you use a led and a resistor, in your case take 3-1.8=2.2 now we asume a typical 20ma led and use ohms law to calculate the minimum resistance which is that Resistance=2.2V(voltage-voltage drop in led, so voltage difference on resistor)/0.02=110ohm.
so if this was a single led running on a 3V supply with the led having a voltage drop of 1.8V and a maximum current of 20ma(typical hobbyist led)then the led would need at least 110Ohm of resistance in front or behind of it to limit the current to 20ma, it is safer to use a slightly higher value of resistor,

Comment: made a mistake in my calculation 3-1.8=1.2 not 2.2 so the real answer here would be 60ohm for 20ma.

Answer (score 1):

A resistor has a voltage drop across it equal to resistance (in ohms) times current (in amps).

So if there's something like an LED where, for example, you want 10mA at 1.8V and you're starting with 3V, you need to drop 1.2V from 10mA, so 10m*R=1.2, R=120ohm. If there's 20 LEDs in parallel and you want 0.2A total, 0.2*R=1.2 so  R=6ohm

If the current is high and resistance is low it's worth checking the power the resistor is dissipating, power=volts*amps, so for 0.2A you'd get 0.2A*1.2V=0.24W, normal size resistors are rated for 0.25W so it would get uncomfortably hot and you should think about using a bigger size

If you're not drawing much current (so if you're using 1.8V as a voltage reference or input to a chip), you can use a potential divider, which is two resistors in series between +V and ground, the ratio of resistors gives the ratio of output voltage, so for example a 1.2kOhm between 3V and 1.8V and a 1.8kOhm between 1.8V and ground. Bigger resistances use less power and get less hot, but if the input resistance to the chip isn't much higher than the resistances you use, the voltage will change

If you're drawing substantial current, and the current varies, you need something active that's more complicated than resistors, like a voltage regulator chip

More context about what you're using the 1.8V for and where the 3V is coming from would help us answer you better!

Comment: Hi, the basics you explain are probably enough to get the question asker going, however I noticed mainly 2 problems, one of them is a theory one the other is one that doesn't exist in theory but will exist in reality.

Comment: 1: the theory about the resistor required has some minor flaws/mistakes according to the general theory. you indeed use the voltage(3v)-the led voltage drop(1.8v) which gives 1.2V, however the problem is behind that according to ohms law R=V/I while you wrote R=V*(I*1000), so for 10ma it would be R=1.2V/0.01A(10ma)=120Ohm(answer was correct in this case just add the calculation)

Comment: 2: in reality all leds are slightly different, so connecting them in parallel behind or in front of one resistor can be quite dangerous, while in most cases i will go right and some modern products even use them like that it isn't good practice for urability since it will in many cases drastically reduce led lifespan, some leds will draw a lot more and some a lot less current even a small difference in internal resistance or voltage drop can do this here. while the leds degrade this might get worse and eventually it will die.

Answer (score 0):

1 resistor by itself cannot lower voltage , more than 1 resistors can by forming a voltage divider.

The values of the resistors must be chosen such that the output impedance is at least x10 value of resistor parallel to it so that the load doesnt change the output voltage very much.