# Do I need to worry about current when using a potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I have a 12 V, 2 A device. I need to be able to change the voltage for this device on the fly to up to 13.5 V. I am not an electrical engineer so please bear with me.

From what I understand each potentiometer has a power rating. I found some 1 kΩ, 10 kΩ, and 100 kΩ rated at 0.25 W.

I think I need to use the following equation: P = V<sup>2</sup>/R.

Therefore 13.5<sup>2</sup> / 10000 = 0.018 W.

Does this mean that I can use a 10 kΩ potentiometer for my case? Or do I need to consider the 2 A and potential of (13.5 * 2 = 27 W) in this circuit?

As a side question, ideally I would use a digital potentiometer for this task so that it can be done remotely; is it possible to do so with these voltages/currents?

Comment: You say you need to change the voltage. Do you mean you need to *power* the device from this variable voltage? If so, a potentiometer absolutely will not work.

Comment: Can you explain the circuit that you want to build? All you said is there's a potentiometer somewhere in it. What matters is not just the fact there's a potentiometer, but also what the potentiometer is connected to. (I bet your idea completely won't work and someone will suggest a better one)

Comment: potentiometer is a pair of adjustable resistors. e.g. turn it halfway and you have 5k and 5k. Would your circuit work if using 5k and 5k resistors?

Comment: This question: [When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider) would be good background reading for why using a potentiometer (a variable voltage divider) won't work in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power rating determines the maximum current that can be run through the resistance track. If we take your 1 kΩ, 0.25 W pot as an example we can calculate from \$ P = I^2R \$ the **max** current as

$$ I_{max} = \sqrt \frac P R =\sqrt \frac {0.25}{1000} = 15.8\ \text {mA}  $$

Obviously from this result you cannot draw 2 A (2000 mA) from the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a potentiometer to change supply voltage and current for a device, because you have to worry about power, amps and voltage. Putting 2A through 10k resistance would mean 20000 volts over it.

Comment: sorry for maybe a dumb question. But, what is the purpose of potentiometer in the circuit then if you cant use it for voltage or current? Thanks! Is it for signal processing or something?

Comment: @Duxa _What_ circuit? You haven't shown any.

Comment: Take an example such as audio amplifier. The potentiometer is not in the current path of the speaker wire. The potentiometer is a control circuit which controls how much the amplifier amplifies.

Comment: @Duxa, the potentiometer is used as a ratiometric divider somewhere in the audio chain at **pre-amplifier** signal levels - typically 0.1 to 1 V and at very low currents. The output signal level is given by the ratio of resistance of the track between wiper and ground / total track resistance. We don't put potentiometers *after* the power amplifier where voltages and currents are much much higher.