# How do I power an STM32 dev board with 9 V properly?

Tags: microcontroller, power, circuit-design, voltage-divider

Dev Board: Discovery board with STM32F411VET

What is happening in the MCU? I saw the datasheet with the 100-pin chip and and saw it has a bunch of VDD pins and a VBat pin but I'm not sure how the 5 V pin connects to those pins.

So I'd like to power a board with a battery and I wasn't really sure how. I saw on the datasheet for the dev board that I can power it through the 5 V pin. So I did that, first setting up a voltage divider to get 5 V from 9 V. Of course once I attached the MCU the values at Vout changed and wasn't enough power for the dev board to do anything but light up slightly (the program did not run). I recorded some values.

Figure 2 and up just exclude the R2 branch, and V_MCU takes place of V_R2.

[image: Voltages and Currents with Different Voltage Dividers]

[[image: Figure 1 Voltage Divider2]

Comment: Voltage dividers should never be used for powering things.

Comment: Series resistors should not be used for powering things  (except with LEDs).

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider

Answer (score 2):

You can download the schematics from the manufacturer.

But the 5V does not connect to the MCU.

Not directly, as there is a 3.3V regulator to convert 5V to 3.3V.

The board accepts 5V from multiple sources. It can not be powered from 9V directly.

And you can't simply have 9V with resistor divider to convert 9V to 5V. Any load will bring the voltage down from 5V so it won't power the board.

You need a regulator which can take 9V in and provide 5V out. A linear regulator would work but will waste almost half the power a heat. It might be best to use a switch mode buck regulator.

So it might not be a good idea to power it with 9V. At least not with 9V battery. Instead, USB power banks can output 5V directly to the board in a compatible way.

Comment: For anyone wondering about the schematic, it is: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group1/2e/42/7b/ea/56/55/40/25/MB1115-F411VE-D01_schematic/files/MB1115-F411VE-D01_Schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.MB1115-F411VE-D01_Schematic.pdf

Comment: The schematic shows that a LD3985 is used to step down to 3V, and the max input voltage for this chip is 6V

Comment: @jb0 Not to mention the other components which are connected to the 5V node and can't handle even 6V. For example the USB OTG subsystem.

Comment: I missed the lD3985 schematic because I thought it was just for the STLINK, in the data sheet have it is in a figure for the STLINK. Hopefully nothing broke in the short time I powered it directly with a 9v. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Hackem2bits You likely did damage it. Unless it was a 9V battery which can't really provide much current, but it still may damage things as there is no overvoltage protection of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage dividers work by drawing a current from the voltage source to ground. The current will drop a certain voltage across each resistor and so when we measure the voltage at the center node (where you have the MCU set up here), you would get 5 V in this case.

However, voltage dividers **only** work if there is not a significant current drawn from another source. In this case, the MCU is going to have to draw some current to power itself. If it drew 100 mA at 5 volts, we could calculate the effective resistance of the MCU at that point.

5 V = 0.1 A · R

Where R is the load resistance of the idealized MCU. Therefore

R = 50 Ω

This "MCU Load" resistance is in parallel with the lower leg of the voltage divider so the equivalent resistance of the lower part of your voltage divider is lower than how you designed it. This means the voltage is no longer 5 V, but much lower. If the current draw were increased, the voltage at the MCU would be even lower.

In order to get around this, you use an integrated circuit that has a feedback loop that maintains the voltage over a wide range of load conditions. The [MC78M05CTG](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/onsemi/MC78M05CTG/919371) would work nicely in your circuit.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing. You say you want to power from a battery and then you talk about 9 volts. I'm going to assume you want to use a standard 9-volt battery, for example, this:
[image]

These batteries are designed for low-power applications. An ARM microcontroller, memory and peripherals will draw much to much power. Either you will be unable to power the board at all or it will last a very short time. You'll need to rethink your plan.

Comment: This is exactly what has happened to me. My 9V battery cannot cope with my MCU using BLE and WiFi. What kind of battery would be normally used to power an MCU with ble and WiFi capabilities? I'm not expecting it to last a lot, as my project's goal is merely my learning. I have though in 2x9V batteries in series.