# Simple probe PCDU

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, logic-level

I am currantly working on an aerospace engineering project at my university which will fly on a sounding-rocket and I really suck at electical engineering, so I basically need a complete explanation of how this works:

I have a sort of small "space-probe", which has a **built-in 3.7V LiPo-cell** (500mAh) and I need **2 power-rails**, which provide **3.3V at 50mA and 5V at (max) 750mA** to the probes dual RP2040 flight computer assembly, the sensors which are connected to the computer via an I2C bus and 2 servos, which will not run simultaneously.

The only thing I came up with yet, is a resistive divider for the 3.7 to 3.3 part, which is pretty wasteful though and will drain the cell way too fast.
Although there are a couple of explanations of how to build step-up and step-down converters, I've not found one yet, which is simple enough for me to understand and I don't just want to copy something I see and not get how it works. It does not need to be adjustable or anything. Just 3.7 to 3.3 and 5.0

Comment: How would you generate a 5V supply from a 3.7V battery with a divider, given that negative value resistors are not easily available? Is there already a step-up regulator in the circuit? Also the individual current requirements of each rail make a big difference. It's sometimes quite reasonable to generate 5V at high current one way and use a much simpler way to generate a relatively tiny current at 3.3V.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany oh, sorry, I should mention, that the voltage divider was only for the 3.7 to 3.3 ;D I didn't invent a negative resistor. I edited the question :)

Comment: What is a "probe" in this context?

Comment: @Hearth In simple terms, it's a soda can sized drop-down experiment, which is supposed to be deployed by a suborbital rocket to collect data, while falling through the atmosphere. The whole mission, including the development and construction of the 8m tall rocket, is conducted by students. I - a starting-out computer scientist - am contributing this little probe experiment as part of climate research efforts of an institute at our uni. For this experiment I also have to start learning about electrical engineering.

Comment: @Caeleste In the context of electrical engineering, the word "probe" has a *very* different meaning; it refers to one of [these](https://ctemedia.s3.amazonaws.com/cte/images/main_product/CT2789A_72dpi.jpg) or [these](https://ast-labs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/997-006Q2-Side.jpg). So your talking about a battery and a computer threw me off quite a bit!

Comment: @Hearth oh, yeah, I should have guessed, that might refer to oscilloscope or multimeter probes :D Updating the question...

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-a-voltage-divider

Comment: What exactly is the 5V for? Perhaps whatever it is could be redesigned to make life easier. RP2040 itself doesn’t need 5V. If ADC is not used then 1.8V is all it needs, assuming the peripherals are OK with that.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The 5V are mainly used for the servo motors (which need min 600mA) and the flight computer which needs 5.0V (@ 12mA) and 11.2-12.8V.
The 750mA requirement is basically the 600mA for the servos + 12mA for the computer + margin.
The flight computer can't be modified, because it's a custom design made by our institute. The 12V are supplied by a separate battery.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Just for clarification, the flight computer is a student developed PCB, manufactured by our institutes own fabrication facility with 2 RP2040s and a bunch of guidance relevant sensors and some logic on it. However it does not supply power for "external use" due to tight reliability requirements. It powers its own devices, but every mission has to build their own PCDU to power the flight computer with 5 and 12V and the flown payload whatever that might be - in my case a couple of sensors, which require 3.3V.

Answer (score 1):

So you need a step-up converter to generate 5V from a Li-ion battery. I will assume the battery has built-in protection, otherwise you will need to add such protection to avoid over-discharging and damaging the battery.

750mA from an 85% efficient switching DC-DC converter will draw about 1.25A from the battery. You can buy a chip, inductor, and some passive components and build this, you can buy a module or a PCB-mount DC-DC converter. The latter may be a good choice for you- switching converters can be a bit finicky about layout, especially those that operate at MHz frequencies and are thus relatively small/light. I'm not going to suggest any particular product, but if you peruse a distributor catalog you can find many options. PCB modules (as opposed to PCB-mount devices) from dubious sources (Amazon, eBay, Ali etc.) aimed at  hobbyist applications are extremely cheap but not always the best quality or performance (perhaps not meeting claims, even), so a few extra dollars may be well-spent and you'll get proper specs and curves to work with.

For 50mA maximum at 3.3V, a linear regulator (sometimes called an LDO, rightly or wrongly) can be used. Nominal power dissipation at 50mA is only 85mW so even a tiny SOT23 regulator can be used. That will add about 80 mA maximum to your 750mA so you need 830mA at 5V  at the input current might be 1.4A. You *could* operate the 3.3V regulator directly from the battery and save a bit of power/battery capacity but the regulation would fail when the battery voltage dropped below the dropout voltage of the regulator (at best a bit more than 3.3V). Again, you can find many such products in distributor catalogs. They're fairly easy to use but you need to pay close attention to the recommendations for capacitors, in particular the output capacitor characteristics. I suggest choosing one that **specifically** says you can use ceramic capacitors.