# Powering Microcontroller from Battery vs. USB Not Working

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, esp32

I have a small Arduino vibration motor. I am controlling it with an ESP32 wroom microcontroller. When I attach the microcontoller to my computer via usb, the board lights up indicating it's working and the motor works as programmed.

**Problem:**
I built a circuit to control the motor with a push button. When I press the button, the microcontroller doesn't light up and the motor spurts on for a second and stops.

I thought the resistor was too high and that it was causing a lack of voltage. So I removed the resistor and the wires started getting hot.

I'm using a 9V battery and 220 Ohm resistor. The motor requires 5V and the microcontroller has a 3V pin. Circuit diagram is below. I'm new to drawing circuit diagrams, so I added a two pictures just in case I am not drawing it correctly.

**What I think is wrong:**
I'm not getting enough power through the circuit.

**What I tried to fix it:**

- Tried different size resistors.
- Used a voltmeter. Put one side of the voltmeter wires on either side of the resistor to see if I was getting enough voltage. But when I did that, it actually seemed like there was a power surge and the motor sped up a little. So I'm not sure if I was doing that properly.
- I hooked the microntroller back up to the computer via usb to make sure I didn't short anything. Worked perfectly.
- I also thought it could be a problem with the fact that the micrcontroller as a 3V input pin but the motor requires 5V. But then why would it work plugged into the computer?

**Question:**
Is there something wrong with my circuit? Or could it be a board problem? What math should I do to see what could be going wrong or if I'm using the right components?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wait what? You connected 9v to mcu which probably takes 5 or 3.3 V as Vin?... Also button seems to only power the mcu when is pressed

Comment: Use buck converter or LDO to get 5V from battery that's what you are getting when you connect mcu via USB to your pc(if you didn't fried the mcu already)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-a-voltage-divider