# Can't get SH1106 1.3 oled to work (SPI)

Tags: arduino, spi, level-shifting, oled

It's my first project this big - an arduino (Pro Micro) based midi controller. After all the research, schematics and pcb designing I got to assembly and wanted to try out the display, but then I can't get it to work!

Example code, from recommended u8g2 lib is:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <U8g2lib.h>
const byte clock = 15;
const byte data = 14;
const byte cs = 9;
const byte reset = 8;

U8G2_SH1106_128X64_NONAME_F_3W_SW_SPI u8g2(U8G2_R0, clock, data, cs , reset);

void setup(void) {
  SPI.begin();
  u8g2.begin();
}

void loop(void) {
  u8g2.firstPage();
  do {
    u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_ncenB14_tr);
    u8g2.drawStr(0,15,"Hello World!");
  } while ( u8g2.nextPage() );
  delay(1000);
}
```

Tried all the listed constructors, SW HW, all the models and buffer sizes.
I run the connections to the display through TXS0104EDR logic converter (SMD, so prototyping off-pcb seems not doable, but maybe I should try?)

Maybe from all the components power draw, 5V actually measures 4.65V.
Voltage divider (5k,10k) when connected to the load measured ~0.8V, so I swapped it for a 5k potentiometer to set the voltage manually to 3.3V

[image]

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

---

So I just swapped the voltage divider for a LD33CV regulator, still nothing.

I'm Starting to wonder if it's not a model suited only for 4pin communication.
In the documentation, some manipulation is needed to work in 3pin mode: IM0 pulled up, DC pulled down, but here's my chip, no IM0 connection:
[image]

Where do you think I should go from here? My ideas:

- Wire a 5v logic signal from let's say A2 to D/C input
- Swap 3.3V CS for D/C, pull CS always low (then somehow omit soft pin requirement)
- Get a different screen capable of 3pin?

**Update:**
I risked one chip, wired all in 5V logic and it worked! :) My first idea, with 5v D/C signal also worked on the pcb.
However tivial, this feels like a win :) It's my first time posting here, so thank you all for support

But some question remains:
Why is it working only in Software-emulated SPI mode? when i change the constructor to hardware(no clock and data pins specified), no more.
It seems very time-inefficient.
loop like this:

```
t = millis() - last;
  last = millis();
  u8g2.clearBuffer();
  u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_ncenB14_tr);
  u8g2.setCursor(0,20);
  u8g2.print(t,10);
  u8g2.sendBuffer();
```

displays around 15 ms.

Comment: You're trying to use a voltage-divider as a power supply. That's not going to work. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-a-voltage-divider

Comment: Hah, I thought since oled use little current I could get away with it :) So a 3.3V linear regulator would be a proper solution?

Comment: It's not the current used that matters, it's the variability of the current. You could get away with a resistor and a zener for a low-tolerance application, but not a two-resistor divider.

Comment: I would have blamed the TXS0104. Most often people ask why their system does not work, and they have a similar level shifter there and used incorrectly. By incorrectly I mean things that are not visible in schematics.

Comment: @Justme when I skipped the TXS, ran on 5v logic, hardware SPI still didn't work.

Comment: @jasioloza I think you are hiding things behind the black box of Arduino. If you stated which MCU that is (Mega328?) and which MCU pins those are, it might be obvious. Now we would have to go look at which Arduino pin is really which MCU pin.

Comment: Question, what do the mystery Arduino libraries do to the PB0/SS pin, on your platform? I believe it is used for a LED, but is it left as input or controlled to output?

Comment: @Justme: Often "incorrectly" means grabbing a "bidirectional" shifter for unidirectional signals.  The direction sensing logic always gets confused.

Comment: @BenVoigt More like using the bidir level shifter outside the specifications it needs to work properly. Like too slow or fast signal edges, too much capacitance from wiring and IC pins, too long wiring so transmission line effects start to give reflections and chip sees multiple edges instead of one. Or just having something with a pull-down there. Or simply missing a bypass cap.

Comment: @Justme: Right, bidi shifters are simply the wrong tool for many scenarios.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not bidi shifters themselves, but bidi shifters like TXS0104 with features you don't expect such as the rise time acceleratos and internal pull-ups.

Comment: @Justme: A bidi shifter by nature needs direction detection logic, which in a scenario like SPI where the direction of each signal is well-defined, can never do better than a unidirectional level shift, and only hope to do as well if everything goes perfectly.  There are applications which need bidi shifters (multimaster scenarios), but they get overused a lot by people not realizing the bidi is a complicated way of figuring out what the engineer already knew.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons why the hardware SPI does not work for you.

Arduino pin 16 is the hardware SPI MOSI data output, but in your schematic you use Arduino pin 14 which is the hardware SPI MISO data input.

In addition, the SPI hardware SS pin is used for onboard LED. That's fine as any pin can be used for SS in software, but the hardware SS pin must still be set as output. If the hardware SPI SS pin is left as an input, expect problems, as the hardware SPI will drop from master to slave mode when SS is input and it goes low. And it can't even be used as input with internal pull-up, because the LED will load it down to logic low.

Comment: Oh my, I did really mistake MISO for MOSI. I'll update when I see what happens with rewiring these two between Arduino and the PCB. Could you elaborate on the RX_led problem? If it's controlling a led, it's not set as output? Pro micro doesn't have an outboard SS connection and the oled libary seem to be using software Chip Select pin, provided in a hardware constructor.

Comment: @jasioloza The hardware SS must be an output, no matter for what you use it, or if you don't even use it for anything.